# Scalarproduct with orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

We are given vectors $a,b$ and an orthogonal matrix $U$. I was wondering if we can say something about $a^TUb$ compared to $a^Tb$?

I know that orthogonal matrices are isometric, does that help in any sense?

Comment: The only idempotent orthogonal matrix is the identity matrix.

Comment: An orthogonal matrix will rotate input vectors; the scalar product (aka dot or inner product) is sensitive to the angle between the two vectors, so a rotation by $U$ should affect things, assuming $U$ is not the identity

Comment: About the only thing you can say for sure is that $|a^\top U b|$ and $|a^\top b|$ are less than or equal to $\|a\|\|b\|$, by Cauchy-Schwarz. Within this constraint, anything is possible.

Comment: @chhro isn't every orthgonal matrix idempotent since $U^TU=\mathbb{1}$? So we have $||Uv||=\sqrt(v^TU^TUv)=\sqrt(v^Tv)=||v||$

Comment: Idempotent means $U^2 = U$. I think you mean, perhaps, "isometric"? It's a term that better describes maps like $x \mapsto Ux$ than matrices like $U$. :-)

Comment: That’s not what idempotent means. Also, it’s $\mathbf{I}$, not $\Bbb{1}$. An operation f is idempotent iff $f^k=f,\forall k\in\Bbb{N},k\gt0$

Comment: Oh sorry, yes of course. My mistake